# ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: html5, enlace, href

al momento de crear un link hacía otro archivo HTML local cuando quiero acceder con Chrome me salta el siguiente error

> ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

El código que estoy usando no tiene errores tipográficos y además ambos archivos están ubicados en la misma carpeta, el nombre del archivo está bien escrito

```
<html>
     <a href= "index.html">Link</a>
</html>
```

Comment: Cómo el error te dice, no encuentra el archivo, añade comillas a Index.html de esta forma `"index.html"`. Busca información de cómo se hace este tipo de links y asegurate que el path indicado es correcto

Comment: el archivo index.html no lo esta encontrando, recuerda que este archivo debe estar en la misma carpeta de tu proyecto, al mismo nivel en este caso

Comment: Perdón, en mi código si que tiene las comillas, ahora acabo de editarlo para evitar confusiones

Comment: Heyner: Como ya dije en el post, el archivo sí está al mismo nivel que el proyecto

Comment: Ya habías hecho la pregunta, se cerró, la eliminaste y volviste a subir otra? https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/487981/chrome-no-encuentra-mi-archivos-html

Comment: Si, porque el error de las comillas no era el problema, yo escribí mal acá el código pero no lo escribí mal en el editor de código, puede ser que el estar desde Android influya en algo?

Comment: La otra pregunta ya tenia varios comentarios y estaba encaminada. Y te estan comentando lo mismo que te dicen aca. Tenes el boton [edit] para arreglar tu publicacion.. y de paso mira [ask]- Estas seguro que todos los archivos estan en el mismo lugar? el archivo tiene permisos?

Comment: @Laureano Lisak, está `index.html` en la misma carpeta que tú archivo dónde haces el link?

Comment: gbianchi: Me cerraron la pregunta así que supuse que no había edición que valiera, por otro lado, si, es más hice pruebas en distintos directorios y nada

Comment: @LaureanoLisak revisa lo que te dice gbianchi, agrega toda la info que nos pueda servir para ayudarte. Puedes añadir capturas o un código más completo haciendo clic en [edit]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: @Jheyman tampoco serviría de mucho, puesto que nisiquiera puedo hacer que funcione ese código tan sencillo como el que puse en la pregunta, supongo que será algo de los permisos que me estoy perdiendo

Comment: @Jheyman y eso que estoy revisando los permisos, supongo que en última instancia será el problema Chrome y los navegadores en general puesto que estos no tienen un permiso total para acceder a los archivos como lo tiene mí editor de código por ejemplo (según el celular, Chrome solo puede acceder a archivos multimedia)

Comment: Igual prueba usando `<a href= "./index.html">Link</a>`

Comment: @Jaime, cuando vuelva a mí casa lo pruebo y actualizo

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar, usando el file:/// por delante del nombre me sale el error "ABOUT:BLANK#BLOCKED"

Comment: @LaureanoLisak tu mismo te estás cerrando a que te podamos ayudar, lee [ask] y añade toda la información posible en [edit], por ejemplo, la estructura del directorio donde están tus archivos. Entre más información nos brindes, mejor, de resto estaremos adivinando.